# How to call remote API in django from views.py?

Tags: django

I'm new to Django, and I got stuck while calling a remote API from `views.py`.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

...

if request.method == 'post':
    r = requests.post('domain_name/api/test/', d=request.POST)
```

This is giving me an error. What is the proper way to to call an API?

Comment: Likely you need to compare this with `request.method == 'POST'`

Comment: what error is it giving? can you post the traceback

Comment: AFAIK its `data` rather than `d`, and `request.POST` has query params you don't really need

Comment: from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
def categorydashboard(request):
     r = request.post('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/Category/getSubCategoryNamev2', d=request.GET)
     return render (request,'categoryDashboard.html',{})                                                                ............................................................................................. It is giving me the AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'post' @Moha369